# Wrap header doesn't work in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, header, styles

Currently I'm programming something in asp.net. I have a gridview of 69ish columns and 250.000 records. I have paging on the gridview and I show 15 records / page.

Now to be able to add more records I want to wrap my header text.

```
For example: | Project Funds in USD | (should it be) --- (what I have now) | Project |
                                                                             Funds
                                                                             in USD
```

In my headerstyle of my gridview I've tried several things:

1. `Wrap="false";`
2. Cssclass -> `white-space:nowrap;`

I have also noticed that when I run the web application locally, IE 'reads' it perfectly and wraps it like I want it to wrap.  However when I publish it to the company web server, it freaks out and does whatever the hell he wants.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: auto; height: auto; margin-top: 5px; clear:both">                
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" 
            DataKeyNames="iol_id" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Rank" HeaderText="Rank" 
                    SortExpression="Rank" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="OI_IV_Status" HeaderText="OI IV Status"
                    SortExpression="OI_IV_Status" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="false" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Supplier_Code" HeaderText="Supplier Code" 
                    SortExpression="Supplier_Code" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Billing_Period" HeaderText="Billing Period" 
                    SortExpression="Billing_Period" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Invoice_Type" HeaderText="Invoice Type" 
                    SortExpression="Invoice_Type" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Invoice_Number" HeaderText="Invoice Number" 
                    SortExpression="Invoice_Number" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Bussiness" HeaderText="Bussiness" 
                    SortExpression="Bussiness" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Payer_LE_Code" HeaderText="Payer LE Code" 
                    SortExpression="Payer_LE_Code" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Payer_LE_Name" HeaderText="Payer LE Name" 
                    SortExpression="Payer_LE_Name" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                ...
            </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

- I have deleted a lot of columns in order to make it look less like a wall of text! :) *

If you guys need any other code, just ask me ;)

Comment: Does the outputted HTML differ on your local server compared to your company webserver? Also you say you are trying to wrap but also that you were trying "`wrap=false`" and "`white-space: nowrap`". Both of these look like they will prevent wrapping. Can you confirm which you are trying to do?

Comment: nope they don't differ. I've been copying exactly the same files from my local environment to the webserver.
I have been trying both seperatly "wrap=false" and "white-space: nowrap;" and together.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# - ASP.NET - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit F12 to get into the developer tools. Check the view mode in both your local and intranet deployments. I have a feeling that IE forces you into compatibility mode on intranets. You can override this behaviour but double check by selecting standard and the compatibility modes in the dropdown to see if this is the issue.

edit:
if it is the issue which you have now said it is the html needs the following meta tag:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

this meta tag must be the first tag in the header

Comment: Sorry but F12 doesn't give my any window. I running Visual Studio 2008. .NET framework 3.5 if that helps you guys :s

Comment: Andy is saying to hit F12 in IE

Comment: What version of IE? Does it work in chrome or firefox? Rather than using IE click on the compatibility icon in the navigation bar its a document icon with a tear. See if the affects the rendering of the grid.

Comment: check out http://thethoughtfulcoder.com/blog/63/Internet-Explorer-8-compatibility-view-and-the-local-intranet-zone

Comment: I have IE 7. However the wrap works if I run the webtool as localhost (in IE). The wrap works also in firefox without any problem.

Comment: You are right Andy, if I run it locally it doesn't go in compatibility mode. However, in the IE Compatitbility Settings there is an option checked to run Intranet webpages in compatibility mode.

Comment: I have amended the answer now for you but you add in a meta tag to stop it happening: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: Thx Andy for all your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

`white-space:nowrap` is to make sure the header DON'T wrap, which is the opposite of what you are trying to do...